# How to combine bold and italic in CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, typography

[This W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp) taught me how to use the CSS `font-style` property to make text bold (equivalent to `<b&g>this</b>` in old-fashioned HTML) as well as how to make text italic (equivalent to`<i>this</i>` in old-fashioned HTML).

However, I can't seem to find anywhere how to make text have both properties at the same time (equivalent to `<b><i>this</i></b>` in old-fashioned HTML).

Is there a way to do this using pure CSS?

I've tried this:

```
font-style: italic bold;
```

The result was that the page ignored both properties, and it was as though I never specified this property at all.

I got the same results when I tried this:

```
font-style: italic, bold;
```

I got a different result when I tried this:

```
font-style: italic; bold;
```

This time, what happened is that it used the first style given (italic) but ignored the second (bold).

Can this be done with pure css?

Comment: Bold is a value for font-weight, not font-style

Comment: where did you read "bold" in the page you linked?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You were close.

`italic` is used with `font-style` whereas bold is used with `font-weight`.

Use:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
```

Answer (score 5):

`font-style` is a single-value property. `bold` is font-weight, anyway. To combine multiple values, you can use the shorthand `font` property. However, the `font` shorthand has required entries: `font-size` and `font-family`. If you don't include both of these in the shorthand, the property will be ignored.

Include these in your `font` shorthand along with `italic bold` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can have an italic and bold font using those 2 properties

```
font-style  : italic
font-weight : bold
```

font-weight doc : [W3Schools font-weight](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp)

font-style doc  : [W3Schools font-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Please have look at this code:

```
font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another reason why W3Schools is bad, you should be using [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) to set bold and [font-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) to set italics.

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
```

Comment: Not to defend w3schools but they don't mention `bold` on their `font-style` page.

Comment: By the Op's statement, seems like it did.

Comment: I'm not really fond of W3Schools either but this time it's not their fault. "bold" isn't mentioned anywhere in the OP's link.

Comment: @epascarello I agree, so I went and checked it out to see if they were that dumb. btw I didn't ding you.

Comment: I figured it had it since OP stated it, was too lazy to look at the link and see. Interesting thing is the browser the OP is using supports bold with font-style.

Answer (score 0):

*Hi, I had the same problem. I followed the above steps specified.*

But, the above answer was **not complete without importing a css file with the specified font style (bold italic)**. You have to **have a .css which imports** the font's **bold italic style** to actually display the desired effect.

This step is often overlooked and can be done very easily.

I'll demonstrate it here ( it's self explanatory but I will show it anyway)

I'll use Google Fonts here, and the specific font-family Lato.

1. Go to [Google-Fonts/Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?subset=tamil&preview.text=Bold%20and%20italic%20text&preview.text_type=custom).

   [Screengrab of Google-fonts/Lato](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzGCU.png).
2. Tick Bold italic or the weight you want. Here I have selected 'Black' (font-weight = 900)

- [Screenshot of the above step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lokbv.jpg)

3. And Finally Import it to you .css file like this

   `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,900&display=swap');`

Answer (score 0):

You done small mistake by adding bold into font-style. Bold is under font-weight. Like below, (Order doesn't matter.)

```
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
```