# Can't combine font-style=italic with font-weight

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm not a css expert and i'm experiencing some trouble with cross-browser behaviour. In Google Chrome, my code works fine. In the other browser's i've tried (Mozilla, Edge, IE) it doesn't; specifically when using these last browsers, **the font-style property seems to exclude the font-weight property**

This is my html and css code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  .non-italic-class{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
  }
  .italic-class{
    font-style: italic;
  }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <span class="non-italic-class">NON ITALIC</span>
  <br>
  <span class="non-italic-class italic-class">ITALIC</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how it looks like in Chrome (fine for me):

[image]

This is how it looks in Mozilla, Edge, IE (wrong for me):

[image]

Am i doing something wrong? Do i need to add some code in order to get the same behaviour with all these browsers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205797/how-to-combine-bold-and-italic-in-css this will help you.

Comment: Try adding vendor prefixes for browser compatibility.

Comment: You haven't got an extra bold, italic futura-pt font on your system. Chrome synthesizes one, the other browsers don't.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks! Could you please explain me how to include it in my project? i've never done it before.